# I am new to magento I want to know where the frontend routers are reflecting in config.xml file custom module?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, frontend, configuration, router

I am new to magento, i want know in config.xml file there are two routers are there. one is for frontend router and other is admin router,please explain where the frontend routers will reflects.
for admin it will reflects on admin url.
I am not getting where fronted routers is reflecting.

Here is the config.xml file

```
<frontend>
        <routers>
            <surgery>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Test_Surgery</module>
                    <frontName>surgery</frontName>
                </args>
            </surgery>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <surgery>
                    <file>surgery.xml</file>
                </surgery>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <surgery>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Test_Surgery</module>
                    <frontName>surgery</frontName>
                </args>
            </surgery>
        </routers>
    </admin>
```

Answer (score 0):

A route will turn a URL into an Action Controller and a method. Unlike other convention based PHP MVC systems, with Magento you need to explicitly define a route in the global Magento config.

For more details, Can you please [read](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-3.html).